# LP Duality. What is the correct dual to this linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

Suppose a linear program that is defined as follows with decision variables $ w, x, y, z$ and parameters  $a, b, c_j, d_i$.

$\min  \sum_{I}^{} a x_{i}  + \sum_{I}^{} b y_{i}$

$s.t.$

$x_{i} \geq w + \sum_{J}^{}  c_{j} z_j   - d_i \ \forall i \in I$

$y_{i} \geq d_i - w + \sum_{J}^{} c_{j} z_j  \ \forall i \in I$

$x_{i}, y_{i} \geq 0 \ \forall i \in I$,
$w \in \mathbb{R} $,
$z_j \in \mathbb{R} \ \forall j \in J$

I get to the following with $u_i$ and $v_i$ as dual variables for the constraints

$\max - \sum_{I}^{} d_i u_{i}  + \sum_{I}^{} d_i v_{i} $

$s.t.$

$u_{i} \leq a \ \forall i \in I$

$v_{i} \leq b \ \forall i \in I$

$ - \sum_{I}^{} u_{i}  + \sum_{I}^{} v_{i} \leq 0$

$ - \sum_{J}^{} c_j u_{i}  + \sum_{J}^{} c_j v_{i} \leq 0 \ \forall i \in I$

$u_{i}, v_i\geq 0 \ \forall i \in I$

but I am not sure how to correctly account for z and c of the primal. Is the above formulation complete and correct?

Comment: You didn't list $w$ among the decision variables or parameters.  Is $w$ a free variable?

Comment: $w$ is also a decision variable, edited the question accordingly. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the primal problem in standard form with the dual variables in parentheses:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i (a x_i + b y_i) \\
&\text{subject to} &x_i - w - \sum_j c_j z_j &\ge -d_i &&\text{for all $i$} &(u_i \ge 0)\\
&&y_i + w - \sum_j c_j z_j &\ge d_i &&\text{for all $i$} &(v_i \ge 0) \\
&&x_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
&&y_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

The dual problem is (with the primal variables in parentheses):
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &\sum_i (-d_i u_i + d_i v_i) \\
&\text{subject to} & u_i &\le a &&\text{for all $i$} &(x_i \ge 0)\\
&& v_i &\le b &&\text{for all $i$} &(y_i \ge 0) \\
&& \sum_i(-u_i + v_i) &= 0 && &(\text{$w$ free}) \\
&& -c_j \sum_i (u_i + v_i) &= 0 &&\text{for all $j$} &(\text{$z_j$ free}) \\
&&u_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
&&v_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: I have to change the original problem to where now the two constraints read $x_{i}  - w - \sum_{J}^{}  c_{ij} z_j  \geq - d_i \ \forall i$ and $y_{i} + w +  \sum_{J}^{} c_{ij} z_j  \geq d_i \ \forall i$. In this edit parameter $c_{ij}$ has a second index and there is a sign change in the second constraint. For the dual problem that leads me to $ \sum_{i} c_{ij} (-u_i + v_i) \ \forall j$ as the last constraint (while the others stay as defined in your answer) but it seems that there is a mistake, at least numerical comparison of primal and dual objectives suggests so.

Comment: The dual change you suggested for the primal change looks correct to me. Do you have a small test instance that yields the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Sure. With $d = [1,2,3,4,5], c = [[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]], a = 0.4, b = 0.2$ I find a primal objective of $1.125$ but get a dual objective of $-1.110$

Comment: With your sample data, the optimal objective value is $0$, attained, for example, by $w=0$, $z_1=1.5$, $z_3=-0.5$, and $x_i=y_i=0$ for all $i$.  Maybe you have a sign wrong somewhere.  Or maybe something is wrong with your $c_{ij}$ indexing.  You have given a $3 \times 5$ matrix, but $c$ should be $5 \times 3$.